# Ayuda para descifrar nombre y apellidos

Tags: traducción

[image]

No consigo descifrar nombre y apellidos

Comment: Solo saco el segundo apellido que es Perez

Comment: Y de nombre parece que pone Honorato pero el primer apellido....

Comment: Complicado, pero basándome en las respuesta previas, lo único que se me ocurre es Honorato Gutiérrez Pérez.

Comment: Coincido con R18. Además, un par de lineas más arriba de la señalada parece que hay otro "Gutierrez" y es muy parecido